# Planning to buy a TV in Dubai to bring to India, what issues may I encounter?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, electronic-items, shopping, dubai

While going to India via Emirates, I am planning to have 1 day's stop at Dubai and meanwhile I want to buy a TV (Samsung or Sony LED TV) to take to India. There are some doubts I have about it though:

1. If I buy the TV then should I be taking that in my Hand Luggage or it will be counted as baggage that needs to be checked in as "Fragile"?
2. I have seen a couple of folks taking TV's in the baggage claim area in Mumbai.  Just wondering what are the supporting documents needed if in case I'm stopped by local officers. Any other troubles with customs in Dubai/India?
3. Is there any market which offers TV's at Discounted rates in Dubai, or do I have to buy from mall itself?  If so, which place will be convenient (i.e Nearest to Airport)?
4. Is it a good idea to buy a TV from Dubai and take it to India? After lots of research I found the Samsung TV that I am looking for worth 45K INR in Dubai, as compared to 75k INR. I live in the USA and don't know of any consequences;

I have gone through couple of forums but haven't got detailed information about the above questions. Please share the experience if you have in your past; will be really helpful.

Comment: Even though I've asked and fought to keep a couple of shopping questions here on travel.se I think this provides a test case of where to draw the line. I think buying travel-related gear while travelling (tent, sleeping bag, phone, gps) should be on-topic, but buying stuff to import back home should be off-topic.

Comment: @HaLaBi: I think customs rules are 100% on-topic. Where to buy is a bit iffy for non-travel-related stuff - we should give that some thought for when the site gets big in the future. I think when we get into brands and prices that's definitely the area the SE network doesn't want as covered in the classic blog post: **[Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)**

Comment: @hippietrail & Halabi : I edited my title & summary a bit based on your feedback. I am buying a product for my personal use.